# DCM and CCM Behaviour in LLC Converters

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, llc-converter, dcm-ccm

I've been refreshing my power electronics knowledge these days. During my re-visit to the LLC converters, I've come across [this](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND9408-D.PDF) application note.

It also explains the behaviour of an LLC converter at DCM and CCM conditions, at page 6. Excerpt from the article:

> As a LLC resonant converter, the major factor that relates with operating in DCM or CCM is load current. At high load current, it tends to work in CCM; at light load situation, it tends to work in DCM.

> In order to show the impact of load current on DCM and CCM, three load conditions are simulated, as shown in Figure 25. At high load currents, D1 and D2 alternately conduct load current. This is CCM. At light load, there are some intervals that the rectifiers do not provide any current to the load, which is the DCM.

And this is the aforementioned Figure-25:
[image]

This does not look correct to me. Considering this statement `At light load, there are some intervals that the rectifiers do not provide any current to the load, which is the DCM.` I can't match the conditions to the curves. The no-current-to-load intervals can be clearly seen in blue and dark green curves.

Is there a mistake in the curves or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, it looks like a mistake to me. Figure 15 and Figure 18 are very similar and labeled correctly.